# replace comma separated values in a sheet uses SORT formula to get sorted results from another sheet

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a sheet called "Form Responses 1" connected with a Google Form, and I made another sheet/tab and used this formula:

```
=SORT('Form Responses 1'!A2:M, 4, TRUE)
```

to sort the responses with a certain order in mind.

Now I have multiple choices answers from column F to Column M with commas separated, I want to add a line break instead of the comma, so I tried in column F this custom formatting.

```
=substitute(F2;",";char(10))
```

And

```
=substitute(F2,",",char(10))
```

but it doesn't work.

What are possible solutions?

Comment: Are you using Excel or Google Sheets? If Excel, try Power Query to split and unpivot the comma-sep responses.

Comment: It's probably working, just not the way you expect. The `LF` character will break inside a cell and can be confirmed by formatting the cell with `Wrap Text`.

Comment: @FlexYourData Since this spreadsheet is connected to a Google Form, it's fair to assume the spreadsheet is a Google Sheets file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first formula used a comma as a function parameter separator, your other formulas should also use commas as a function parameter separator.

Your second formula works fine for me:

[image: Formula and result of G2]